# Write text from .txt file to Rich Text Box from different text files?

Tags: c#

So i'm making a program that needs to write info from a text box to a txt file then read the info from the txt file in a rich text box. Heres what I have so far.

```
private void btn_Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + txt_Key.Text + ".txt"))
        MessageBox.Show("File already exists");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + txt_Key.Text + ".txt");
    else
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + txt_Key.Text + ".txt", true);

        sw.WriteLine("Dog: " + txt_Name.Text);

        txt_Name.Clear();
        sw.WriteLine("Owner: " + txt_Owner.Text);

        txt_Owner.Clear();
        sw.WriteLine("Age: " + nud_Age.Value.ToString());
        nud_Age.Value = 0;

        sw.WriteLine("Breed: " + cmb_Breed.SelectedItem.ToString());

        if (cmb_Breed.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Sub Specie: " + cmb_Shepard.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmb_Shepard.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else if (cmb_Breed.SelectedIndex == 7 && ckb_Pedigree.Checked == true)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Pedigree: Yes");
        }
        else if (cmb_Breed.SelectedIndex == 7 && ckb_Pedigree.Checked == false)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Pedigree: No");
        }
        txt_Key.Clear();
        sw.WriteLine("Comments: " + txt_Com.Text);
        sw.Close();
        txt_Com.Clear();
    }
}

private void btn_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + txt_Key.Text, true);
    rtb_Info.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

As you can see in my write button I have

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + txt_Key.Text + ".txt", true);
```

which does work and makes a txt file with the key that I generated but in my read button it says that the file doesn't exist. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, it is because code is clearing  `txt_Key` Text value after writing to file.

You should think of either removing below line or having a class field and preserving it for next read.

```
 txt_Key.Clear();
```

I would also suggest use debugger to step in and see what exact path been constructed.

On a side note, it is *not* advisable to write into an OS folder.

Comment: Ok that was it, thanks a lot. Also for some reason the text box that contains the key is cleared when I press the write button, any ideas why?

Comment: Do you mean `txt_Key` value?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem but thanks a lot for your help!